# Julia imresize function definition is vague

Tags: image-processing, julia

[Here](https://github.com/JuliaImages/ImageTransformations.jl/blob/e8f4bc58062b5c7e589a5e3593fac33e4c5e535a/src/resizing.jl) the function `imresize` from `ImageTransformation.jl` is defined.
On line 164 there is this expression:

```
resized[I] = original(I_o...)
```

From Julia's documentation I understood the triple dot is called splatting and it unpacks an argument into multiple arguments. For example `I_o` is a tuple here. My issue is that I cannot find any trace of a function called `original` in the mentioned Julia file.
Where is `original`? From the code itself I have the impression that `original` should be an array and indeed on line 147 the type of `original` is annotated as `AbstractInterpolation` yet in turn I could not find any object of such type in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [function declaration](https://github.com/JuliaImages/ImageTransformations.jl/blob/e8f4bc58062b5c7e589a5e3593fac33e4c5e535a/src/resizing.jl#L147) reads:

```
function imresize!(resized::AbstractArray{T,N}, original::AbstractInterpolation{S,N}) where {T,S,N}
```

Hence, `original` is the parameter of the `imresize!` function.

Now, you can see that this is called with paranthesis `()`. This happens because a [functor](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/#Function-like-objects) has been defined.

This functor seems to be defined outside of this package but you can see in the package how it is used:

```
@inline _getindex(A, v) = A[v...]
@inline _getindex(A::AbstractInterpolation, v) = A(v...)
```

so simply it is used to yield an interpolation element.

You can find the actual declaration of this functor in the `Interpolations` package (for each interpolation type). For an example:

```
@inline function (itp::BSplineInterpolation)(x::Vararg{UnexpandedIndexTypes})
    itp(to_indices(itp, x)...)
end
```

Source: https://github.com/JuliaMath/Interpolations.jl/blob/33409a657cacabf877681439605f16431f4bc8f4/src/b-splines/indexing.jl#L46